# "Under heaven" or "under the heavens" on day three of creation?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, creation

The ESV translation uses the terms "Heaven" and "the heavens" in verses 8 and 9 of Genesis 1 in a way I find confusing:

> <sup>8</sup>And God called the expanse **Heaven**. And there was evening and there was morning, the second day.
>
> <sup>9</sup>And God said, “Let the waters under **the heavens** be gathered together into one place, and let the dry land appear.” And it was so. <sub><sub>[ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Genesis+1%3A8-9)</sub></sub>

Does the Hebrew indicate a plural in verse 9 and singular in verse 8, or is it more consistent with the singular used in both cases by the NET translation ("sky" and "the sky" respectively).